# Is it possible to run Docker on a hypervisor type 1?

Tags: docker, vmware-esxi, hyper-v, linux-kernel, hypervisor

Is it possible to run Docker bare metal on a type 1 hypervisor such as VMware and Hyper-V?

Docker uses that same kernel as the host. So if the hypervisor is based on linux,  does that work? Is there such a hypervisor?

Or have I misunderstood the whole topic?

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're asking. You can run Docker under Linux. If your hypervisor can boot Linux, then you can run Docker on that hypervisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers are a lightweight process isolation technology, like a chroot or jail. Not a new idea, but popular these days.

The point initially was to not need (physical or virtual) hardware and the associated operating system. Also known as bare metal. Although of course running it in a VM is also possible.

Decide on which container tools you want to use. Docker is one, there are others.

A container runtime is an application that makes use of special sandbox features. It is not an operating system or a hypervisor by itself. So decide on the operating system and hardware to run this compute workload on.

Almost certainly the commodity containers assume Linux, although you can run Windows containers in Docker. As you have the choice of [popular Linux distros](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/) or [distros purpose built for containers](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/faq/#_which_container_runtimes_are_available_on_fedora_coreos) you also have the choice of whether to run in bare metal or in a VM. Which comes down to your personal preference and familiarity around managing VMs or not.

Not to endorse any particular project, but some examples could illustrate the diversity of options.   Both these are Linux containers.

- Docker installed in Ubuntu, running as a VM in a Proxmox cluster.
- Fedora CoreOS, on bare metal in an OpenStack cluster, running Docker for now and Kubernetes as a later project.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. Hyper-V does not have a Linux Kernel, it's Windows. To run Docker on Windows you need to run it in a VM. While ESX was Linux based, [ESXi is not](https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2013/06/its-a-unix-system-i-know-this.html), therefore I doubt running Docker directly on it is even possible, even if it were it would be hacky and certainly would void your support.